# After reinstalling Atom text editor I lost almost all core features

Tags: 14.04, atom

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 OS. I reinstalled Atom text editor  (I installed it by following instructions @ Atom GitHub ). I am using 64 bit version. I lost a lot of features such as, searching specific characters (CTRL+F), settings (packages, themes, etc...CTRL+,), I can no longer change document language, etc...for example if I want to open settings (CTRL+,) it opens empty config file - screenshot: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem you need to find:

.atom folder

(reinstalling atom doesn't touch this file btw)

There are two ways to find it on Ubuntu 14.04

1) command line
`$ cd .atom`

2) open nautilus files explorer ui (`nautilus`) go to home directory, it is the one that is opened by default, go View -> Show hidden files  and delete .atom folder (or rename, copy-paste) and then reinstall Atom.

Answer can be found here:
https://discuss.atom.io/t/ubuntu-14-04-after-reinstalling-atom-i-lost-alot-of-features-and-cant-get-them-back/24341